# Ubuntu 12.04 Compiling Android master

Tags: android, ubuntu, compilation

Set up environment as guided. Had to manually install one dependancy, it removes xorg and ubuntu desktop for some reason when you do.
Installed all things, make version 3.82 so no threading crash, using ccache.
Ran into this crash, any ideas? Clean install, 4GB ram, quad core processor, "lunch aosp_arm-eng; make clean; make -j4":

```
Warning: AndroidManifest.xml already defines versionCode (in http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android); using existing value in manifest.
Warning: AndroidManifest.xml already defines minSdkVersion (in http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android); using existing value in manifest.
Warning: AndroidManifest.xml already defines targetSdkVersion (in http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android); using existing value in manifest.
Install: out/target/product/generic/system/app/Email.apk
/home/codelion/android/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: warning: hidden symbol 'SkBitmap::lockPixels() const' in out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/skia_skia_library_gyp_intermediates/skia_skia_library_gyp.a(SkBitmap.o) is referenced by DSO out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/libjnigraphics.so
/home/codelion/android/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: warning: hidden symbol 'SkBitmap::unlockPixels() const' in out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/skia_skia_library_gyp_intermediates/skia_skia_library_gyp.a(SkBitmap.o) is referenced by DSO out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/libjnigraphics.so
/home/codelion/android/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: warning: hidden symbol 'SkBitmap::notifyPixelsChanged() const' in out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/skia_skia_library_gyp_intermediates/skia_skia_library_gyp.a(SkBitmap.o) is referenced by DSO out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/libjnigraphics.so
external/chromium_org/content/browser/renderer_host/media/media_stream_manager.cc:1451: error: undefined reference to 'media::FakeVideoCaptureDeviceFactory::FakeVideoCaptureDeviceFactory()'
external/chromium_org/content/browser/renderer_host/media/media_stream_manager.cc:1462: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for media::FileVideoCaptureDeviceFactory'
external/chromium_org/content/browser/service_worker/service_worker_database.cc:173: error: undefined reference to 'content::ServiceWorkerRegistrationData::ServiceWorkerRegistrationData()'
external/chromium_org/content/browser/service_worker/service_worker_database.cc:194: error: undefined reference to 'content::ServiceWorkerRegistrationData::~ServiceWorkerRegistrationData()'
external/chromium_org/content/browser/service_worker/service_worker_database.cc:125: error: undefined reference to 'content::ServiceWorkerRegistrationData::ServiceWorkerRegistrationData()'
external/chromium_org/content/browser/service_worker/service_worker_database.cc:138: error: undefined reference to 'content::ServiceWorkerRegistrationData::~ServiceWorkerRegistrationData()'
external/chromium_org/content/browser/service_worker/service_worker_database.cc:148: error: undefined reference to 'content::ServiceWorkerResourceRecord::ServiceWorkerResourceRecord()'
external/chromium_org/content/browser/service_worker/service_worker_database.cc:155: error: undefined reference to 'content::ServiceWorkerResourceRecord::~ServiceWorkerResourceRecord()'
external/chromium_org/content/common/gpu/media/android_video_encode_accelerator.cc:78: error: undefined reference to 'media::VideoEncodeAccelerator::~VideoEncodeAccelerator()'
external/chromium_org/content/common/gpu/media/video_decode_accelerator_impl.cc:11: error: undefined reference to 'media::VideoDecodeAccelerator::~VideoDecodeAccelerator()'
external/chromium_org/components/autofill/core/browser/phone_number_i18n.cc:294: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber(i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneNumber const&)'
external/chromium_org/components/autofill/core/browser/phone_number_i18n.cc:94: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber()'
out/target/product/generic/obj/GYP/shared_intermediates/protoc_out/third_party/libphonenumber/phonenumbers/phonenumber.pb.h:59: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneNumber::CopyFrom(i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneNumber const&)'
external/chromium_org/components/autofill/core/browser/phone_number_i18n.cc:94: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneNumber::~PhoneNumber()'
external/chromium_org/components/autofill/core/browser/phone_number_i18n.cc:242: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber()'
external/chromium_org/components/autofill/core/browser/phone_number_i18n.cc:162: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber()'
external/chromium_org/components/autofill/core/browser/phone_number_i18n.cc:162: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneNumber::~PhoneNumber()'
external/chromium_org/components/autofill/core/browser/phone_number_i18n.cc:183: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber()'
external/chromium_org/components/autofill/core/browser/phone_number_i18n.cc:183: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneNumber::~PhoneNumber()'
external/chromium_org/components/autofill/core/browser/phone_number_i18n.cc:211: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneNumber::~PhoneNumber()'
external/chromium_org/content/public/renderer/render_frame_observer.cc:28: error: undefined reference to 'content::RenderFrameImpl::RemoveObserver(content::RenderFrameObserver*)'
external/chromium_org/content/public/renderer/render_frame_observer.cc:21: error: undefined reference to 'content::RenderFrameImpl::AddObserver(content::RenderFrameObserver*)'
external/chromium_org/content/public/renderer/render_view_observer.cc:28: error: undefined reference to 'content::RenderViewImpl::RemoveObserver(content::RenderViewObserver*)'
external/chromium_org/content/public/renderer/render_view_observer.cc:21: error: undefined reference to 'content::RenderViewImpl::AddObserver(content::RenderViewObserver*)'
external/chromium_org/content/renderer/media/android/stream_texture_factory_synchronous_impl.cc:64: error: undefined reference to 'content::RenderThreadImpl::current()'
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/content_content_app_both_gyp_intermediates/content_content_app_both_gyp.a(content_main_runner.o):content_main_runner.cc:function content::RunNamedProcessTypeMain(std::string const&, content::MainFunctionParams const&, content::ContentMainDelegate*)::kMainFunctions: error: undefined reference to 'content::RendererMain(content::MainFunctionParams const&)'
out/target/product/generic/obj/GYP/shared_intermediates/protoc_out/third_party/libphonenumber/phonenumbers/phonemetadata.pb.h:1453: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneMetadata::default_instance()'
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_pair.h:68: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneMetadata::PhoneMetadata(i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneMetadata const&)'
external/chromium_org/third_party/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/repeated_field.h:335: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::NumberFormat::NumberFormat()'
out/target/product/generic/obj/GYP/shared_intermediates/protoc_out/third_party/libphonenumber/phonenumbers/phonemetadata.pb.h:1621: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneMetadata::default_instance()'
out/target/product/generic/obj/GYP/shared_intermediates/protoc_out/third_party/libphonenumber/phonenumbers/phonemetadata.pb.h:1579: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneMetadata::default_instance()'
out/target/product/generic/obj/GYP/shared_intermediates/protoc_out/third_party/libphonenumber/phonenumbers/phonemetadata.pb.h:1663: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneMetadata::default_instance()'
external/chromium_org/third_party/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/repeated_field.h:339: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::NumberFormat::MergeFrom(i18n::phonenumbers::NumberFormat const&)'
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_pair.h:68: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneMetadata::PhoneMetadata(i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneMetadata const&)'
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_pair.h:51: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneMetadata::~PhoneMetadata()'
external/chromium_org/third_party/libphonenumber/src/phonenumbers/phonenumberutil.cc:674: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneMetadataCollection::PhoneMetadataCollection()'
external/chromium_org/third_party/libphonenumber/src/phonenumbers/phonenumberutil.cc:725: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneMetadataCollection::~PhoneMetadataCollection()'
external/chromium_org/third_party/libphonenumber/src/phonenumbers/phonenumberutil.cc:694: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneMetadata::PhoneMetadata(i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneMetadata const&)'
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_pair.h:62: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneMetadata::PhoneMetadata(i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneMetadata const&)'
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_pair.h:51: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneMetadata::~PhoneMetadata()'
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_pair.h:51: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneMetadata::~PhoneMetadata()'
external/chromium_org/third_party/libphonenumber/src/phonenumbers/phonenumberutil.cc:694: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneMetadata::~PhoneMetadata()'
external/chromium_org/third_party/libphonenumber/src/phonenumbers/phonenumberutil.cc:1940: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneNumber::MergeFrom(i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneNumber const&)'
external/chromium_org/third_party/libphonenumber/src/phonenumbers/phonenumberutil.cc:2166: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber(i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneNumber const&)'
external/chromium_org/third_party/libphonenumber/src/phonenumbers/phonenumberutil.cc:2599: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber(i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneNumber const&)'
external/chromium_org/third_party/libphonenumber/src/phonenumbers/phonenumberutil.cc:2600: error: undefined reference to 'i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber(i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneNumber const&)'
external/chromium_org/content/renderer/in_process_renderer_thread.cc:23: error: undefined reference to 'content::RenderThreadImpl::RenderThreadImpl(std::string const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libwebviewchromium_intermediates/LINKED/libwebviewchromium.so] Error 1
codelion@ubuntu:~/android$
```

Comment: I think `master` branch is not indented to be fully buildable

Comment: @sherpya Ah how do I go about building android KitKat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

choose a tag from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+refs

example:

`$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.4.2_r2`

Comment: Figured out how to do this with google! Thanks a ton, would never have thought of that. Building guide should probably say something about that.